# Authenticate to an API with OWASP ZAP without using OpenAPI or Swagger specs

Tags: authentication, jwt, owasp, zap

I am trying to authenticate to my API to perform some passive/active scan using OWASP ZAP.

I don't have any Swagger or OpenAPI specification, but I have some HTTP tests (Javascript) that might help. However, I can not figure out to authenticate to my API with ZAP.

Ideally I would like to automate the scan given some specs (in whatever format ZAP understands, but not automatic tools like OpenAPI Swagger), a URL entry-point and username/password, but I am stuck with more fundamental steps like the authentication.

I've been following this guide: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/ui/dialogs/session/context-auth/

I added a username/password pair in Session > Contexts > Default Context > Users:

[image]

I then provided the details about the authentication API endpoint in Sessio > Context > Default Context > Authentication:

[image]

I made sure the button is pushed for "Forced User Mode enabled" (see the red circle in the previous screenshot on the "user details".

Then I right clicked on my "Default Context" (I created this with this name, nothing to do with ZAP terminology, it's just a ZAP Context) and clicked on "Active Scan".

Then I clicked on the button "Start Scan" from the pop-up window after the right click.

Then nothing happens. I don't see anything moving or logging or blinking.

1. How do I authenticate to my API with OWASP ZAP?
2. How do I reuse the JWT token to be used in other HTTP requests as an header?
3. Is there a way I could mime what I do in the HTTP integration tests to let ZAP discover issues with HTTP paths, HTTP query parameters and so on?
4. How can I export the above into a script I could invoke from the command line?

**EDIT 1**

This is not a website with HTML or a webapp. This is just a REST API via HTTPS with requests/responses, paths, query parameters and headers.

The "Include Context" does not contain any URL. However I just tried again adding the URL I specified in the "Authentication" menu, then tried again with the "Active Scan" and nothing happens.

The login/logout regex in "Authentication" were not containing anything because there is no such "logout" - the JWT token just expires and the request to any API endpoint is not valid any more.
Anyway I added the HTTP path (not the protocol or the domain/host, just the path without any /) for the "login" URL to both the regex fields in the form on ZAP. Then tried again "Active Scan" and nothing happens.

- What is this "Active Scan" supposed to do? Do I have to provide all the valid paths? What about the query parameters?
- How can I obtain the JWT token from the "login" API endpoint (it's not a webpage), and reuse it as an HTTP header during the scan?
- How do I passively scan any endpoint starting from e.g. the "login" API endpoint (again - not a webpage, just a REST endpoint).

**EDIT 2**

I am using ZAP 2.9.0 via `snap` on Linux, there is no other version available:

```
$ snap find zaproxy
Name     Version  Publisher  Notes    Summary
zaproxy  2.9.0    psiinon    classic  OWASP ZAP, a tool for finding vulnerabilities in web applications
$ snap install zaproxy --classic
zaproxy 2.9.0 from Simon Bennetts (psiinon) installed
```

*EDIT 3*

I added this regex `https?:\/\/example.org\/.*` (with my host, not "example") to:

- the "Include in Context" menu item
- the "Authentication" menu item in both "login" and "logout" regex patterns.

Then tried again the "Active Scan": nothing happens - no output in the tabs on the lower part of the window, no logs, no blinking semaphores.

Answer (score 2):

So you seem to have missed two key details.

1. You didn't mention what's included in the Context, or that you'd configured Include in Context pattern(s).

[image]

2. Also looking at your screenshot you haven't identified logged in or logged out identifiers so zap can never know what state it is in.

> How can I obtain the JWT token from the "login" API endpoint (it's not a webpage), and reuse it as an HTTP header during the scan?

[image]

In Zap 2.10 you can also setup auth polling as a verification strategy.

If you have a non-standard auth mechanism then there are various options, such as using the Replacer add-on or an HttpSender script to set/update a header/token value. As of 2.10.0 this can also be done via env vars:
https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/start/features/authentication/

> What is this "Active Scan" supposed to do? Do I have to provide all the valid paths? What about the query parameters?

This is why importing OpenAPI etc is valuable. Other options are to proxy functional tests. Zap has to be aware of the content/functionality in order to test it effectively.

> How do I passively scan any endpoint starting from e.g. the "login" API endpoint (again - not a webpage, just a REST endpoint).

Passive scanning takes place on proxied or spidered traffic.

> The "Include Context" does not contain any URL. However I just tried again adding the URL I specified in the "Authentication" menu, then tried again with the "Active Scan" and nothing happens.

Include in Context should be a regex pattern that will match your endpoints, unless you are literally only testing a single specific URL. Ex: `https?:\/\/example.org/.*` (`.*` being regex wildcard and matching anything on example.org/)

Comment: I added more details in the edit above. Just to make sure: this is a REST API, there is no website to crawl or anything like a login webpage or logout button. Thanks

Comment: OK so I see this thing about the proxy with a browser. But how do I target from ZAP some Node.js specs I run on the command line with `npm run test`? Those specs contain all these URLs and HTTP query parameters and HTTP headers. I can not use a browser because this is a REST API - I can use Postman though - but it's not exactly a browser. The language is not a problem, I could use Python as well or `curl`.

Comment: You can set a proxy for postman, selenium, curl, etc. On *nix platforms you can also set proxy via env vars.

Comment: You can with npm too: $ npm config set proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>
$ npm config set https-proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port> Ref: https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/how-to-run-npm-behind-a-proxy-server-a-step-by-step-guide/19386

Comment: OK thanks, but what are the proxy details for ZAP? I mean: in my understanding all the `npm` traffic should go through ZAP as a proxy right? Also: `npm` is just used to run Javascript specs for Node.js but the Operating System process is the `node` command.

Comment: They’re whatever you set them as, by default localhost:8080